# Extend menu items to full width - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menuitem, nav

I currently have a website which I would like the menu items to extend to the full width of the menu. Currently, it's something like this:

```
[home | menu item 1 | menu item 2 | menu item 3 | contact------------------------]
```

I would like it to be more like this:

```
[--home-- | ---menu item 1--- | ---menu item 2--- | ---menu item 3--- | -contact-]
```

How can I achieve this?

Wesbite: http://dietindustries.com/

CSS of the navbar:

```
.main-navigation {
display: block;
float: left;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.main-navigation ul {
display: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.main-navigation li {
position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply next CSS to your website:

```
.main-navigation ul {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
          -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
              justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .main-navigation li {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          -ms-flex: auto;
              flex: auto;
    }
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I added this CSS, but it made no change. Any ideas why? https://prnt.sc/ida0p2

Comment: Check for cached stylesheet, ensure that it's applied in Chrome dev tools and not overridden by @media queries or some other styles.

Comment: I tested it in Chrome dev tools changing styles there manually. You might need to check for overrides, since I was putting those directly into style attribute.

Comment: I did a hard refresh - and checked in chrome dev. The changes are present in the CSS, but the menu still looks the same.

Comment: So the menu is full width on your end?

Comment: Yes I can take a look later again, but it will be in couple hours

Comment: @Zeke Any ideas?

Comment: So the code does save and is visible when inspecting in chrome. Here is a screenshot of the website (how it looks on my end) and the code next to it (not working). https://prnt.sc/idbwyd

Comment: As I said - it gets overridden by media queries. http://snpy.in/N1FtpV http://snpy.in/xCPIO1

Comment: Ah ok I didn't realize that was the case. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Remove your media query for now. You might add it later for responsiveness. I cannot build all the menu for yourself. This is just workable solution, now it's your turn :)

Comment: Just to be sure, If I remove the media query then the site will no longer be responsive? Is there a way to have the menu be full width (extended) and responsive?

Comment: Man, just remove media query for this element. Or put the same statements there for a moment. I media query will not ruin all the website. It's only related to this element.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. It's all full width and looks great. Just how can I center the text inside the menu items?

Comment: Add `text-align: center` to `.main-navigation li`

Comment: Yes, worked like a charm. THANK YOU! Much appreciated!

Comment: Yup, you got it.